# How to crawl all url in AJAX pages?

Tags: ajax, html, scrapy, web-crawler, splash-screen

I use scrapy and splash to crawl all url in website. In some website with static html, It works very good! But when I crawled some website has AJAX page, and html5 I cannot get any url (Example: http://testphp.vulnweb.com/AJAX/, http://testhtml5.vulnweb.com). Anyone has solution for this problem? 
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Use **Request** package-python

You can generate the request for the content and get the response.

Example code [here](https://github.com/vj-09/Web-scraping/blob/master/ajex_call_scrap.py)